# Snowflake Authentication Token expired (390114) - Is there a heartbeat code for Snowflake-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have developed a Flask application connecting to Snowflake DB as the backend using SQLAlchemy. I ran into Snowflake authentication token expired issue if the website remains idle for more than 4 hrs. I looked over in Google and found an answer

https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/issues/160

but it doesn't seem valid for Snowflake-SQLAlchemy.

I implemented a heartbeat code using APScheduler which fires "Select 1" every 50 mins but if the session is active in the browser (SSO) it throws "Authentication token has expired" error.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('snowflake://<connection-string>' )
connection = engine.connect()
names = connection.execute_query("select names from employees")

def sensor():
    """ Function for scheduling purposes. """
    v = cursor.execute("""select 1""")
    v = v.fetchall()
    print(v)

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(sensor,'interval',minutes=50)
sched.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the internal implementation of snowflake python connector heartbeat like this:

```
    from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

    engine = create_engine(
        URL(
            account=DB_ACCOUNT,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD
        ),
        pool_size=50, 
        max_overflow=100,
        connect_args={
            'client_session_keep_alive': True,
        })
    Session = sessionmaker(engine)
```

If you don't use an engine, you can also pass the same `client_session_keep_alive` arg to a connection options ([source](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html)):

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
   user='<user_name>',
   password='<password>',
   account='myorganization-myaccount',
   client_session_keep_alive=True
)
```

The connector will then start a background thread that will force sending a heartbeat to snowflake, so if the token is expiring it will refresh it. What you implemented with `select 1` should also work, but it will cost you a little compute.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is years after the question has been asked. This is my first answer on SO - so probably a good place to practice :)

I suspect there are two separate things in play here - the first is keepalive of a session, which has been answered by others.

The second (and which seems to be your problem) is the time-to-live of your JWT - which is something separate from your session.

No matter what - that JWT token has a lifetime of one hour max. You will therefore need to implement a token refresh strategy.

The time-to-live of the JWT is documented here (halfway down the page - in a note)
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/authenticating.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-session-keep-alive

Try Client Session Keep Alive to keep the session active.