# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 390114 (08001):

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Created a Flask app that uses Flask SQLAlchemy to insert records into a Snowflake table.  It works great locally, in staging, and production, but it occasionally gives me the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 390114 (08001): Authentication token has expired.  The user must authenticate again.

I spoke to one of our DBA's and was told to add `client_session_keep_alive=True` to the end of my URI.  I have tried this and it still gives me the token expired error.

Has anyone had any luck getting this to work.

Comment: This may have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699000/snowflake-authentication-token-expired-390114-is-there-a-heartbeat-code-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `connection.close()`  and `engine.dispose()` worked for me. Has been around 12 hours and hasn't given me the token expired error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Snowflake integration object:

```
create or replace api integration demonstration_external_api_integration_01
api_provider=aws_api_gateway
api_aws_role_arn='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my_cloud_account_role'
api_allowed_prefixes=('https://xyz.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/production')
enabled=true;
```